# Spring Data JPA XRef With PK Object Mapping

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a hard time getting Spring Data to persist the values into an XREF Table. I'm attempting to talk to an existing DB so i cannot change the schema which would have made this easier.

[image: Here is shortened schema]

Classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_type")
class UserType {
   @Id
   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
class UserRole {
   @Id
   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="company")
class Company{
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private UUID id;

   @Column(name="name")
   private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class User {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private UUID id;

   @Column(name="email")
   private String email;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinTable
   private UserType userType;

   //not sure what to do here or which JoinTable/ManyToOne/Etc
   private UserCompanyAccess userCompanyAccess;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_company_access")
class UserCompanyAccess {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserCompanyAccessId userCompanyAccessId;

    // not sure of relationships here either
    private User user;
    private Company company;
    private UserRole userRole;
    
    @Embeddable
    static class UserAccessCompanyId implements Serializable {
        @Column(name="id")
        private UUID id;
    } 
}
```

I have tried many different combinations of @JoinColumns specifying the user(id) and userAccessCompany(user_id) as well with company. The code compiles but at runtime hibernate either throws an error saying company_id not provided or other random exceptions regarding trying to compare uuid to character varying etc which was really weird. Any help would be appreciated. I have done many @OneToMany/@ManyToOne/@ManyToMany but somehow never through spring data with an XREF table where the PK is not a composite of the 2 joining tables. That's what is throwing me off. Otherwise the @EmbeddedId would be the combination of the two.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a stack trace showing the actual errors. Also, why is the `userType` field in the `User` class designated as a `@JoinTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dark brown section of the spreadsheet is confusing, because it suggests there's a CompanyUser table that you haven't mentioned elsewhere. Is that an issue?

Regardless, it's a shame you can't adjust the schema, because this design has a lot of flaws. However, it should still be possible to use it. I'm a little stale on Java and Spring/Boot, and I don't have a useful way to test them easily, but you may have better luck with these:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_type", table="user_type", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private UserType userType;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="user_type")
class UserType {
    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_role")
class UserRole {
    @Id
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="company")
class Company{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user_company_access", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "user_id", "company_id" })
})
class UserCompanyAccess {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role", table="user_role", referencedColumnName = "name")
    private UserRole userRole;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", table="user", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", table="company", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Company company;
}
```

Explanation: The user_company_access table is where everything ultimately gets tied together. It's designed such that any particular combination of user and company to be unique, and @UniqueConstraint enables that in the code; you don't really need an embeddable object for that.

Comment: I will test this today and let you know. Thanks!